# This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled

Tags: android

HP Compaq 6200 Pro SFF PC 64 BIT

Trying build an app but every time i build i get this message.

I have tried multiple solutions 
I enabled in the BIOS 
I set the bit 
I tried the intel workaround. 
I NEED HELP

Answer (score 2):

What matters if the CPU - must be Intel processor that supports VT and NX bit (XD) - you can check your CPU # at http://ark.intel.com 
Also make sure hyperV off     bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
               XD bit is on   bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn 
Use the installer from 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager 
If you're using Avast,  disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again

Answer (score 0):

According to [This link (developer.android.com)](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration):

> Virtual machine acceleration for Windows requires the installation of the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel HAXM). The
> software requires an Intel CPU with Virtualization Technology (VT)
> support and one of the following operating systems:
>
> 1 - Windows 7 (32/64-bit)
>
> 2 - Windows Vista (32/64-bit)
>
> 3 - Windows XP (32-bit only)

Answer (score 0):

- Unchecking the Avast Antivirus feature "Enable Hardware Assisted Virtualization" under `Settings > Troubleshooting` solved my problem.
- Now restart the computer
- Now install the HAXM installer and it will install successfully.
- Now start the AVD and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

restart window and go to BIOS --> Enabled intel virtualization technology --> save and exit --> open window and re-install HAXM.exe